# Isomorphism between matrix groups and multiplicative cyclic group of finite field

Tags: matrices, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

Suppose $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a finite field and $\mathbb{F}^*_{p^n}$ is the set of all non zero elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. The set $\mathbb{F}^*_{p^n}$ is a cyclic multiplicative group. In several references such as [this book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Finite_Fields_and_Their.html?id=AvY3PHlle3wC&redir_esc=y) and [this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Wardlaw47052.pdf), it is states that there is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}^*_{p^n}$ and $\{\mathbf{A}^j : j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ whose characteristic polynomial is primitive polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x)) $.

For example, there is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}^*_{8} = (\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1))^* $ and $\{\mathbf{A}^j : j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for $\mathbf{A} =$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1 \\
1&0&0 \\
0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}

To construct such matrix, the idea is to find a primitive polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x)) $ (which is also irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$) and construct a companion matrix $\mathbf{A}$ from $p(x)$.

For example the, in $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1) $, we can take $p(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ as our primitive polynomial and construct the (companion) matrix $\mathbf{A}$ as explained above.

The question is, how to complete the formal proof of this proposition?
(This problem is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595761/order-of-matrix-and-monic-irreducible-polynomial-over-finite-field), which I posted previously).

Comment: Ok. With that primitive polynomial $p(x)$ and the companion matrix $A$ in place the isomorphism of multiplicative groups is simply
$$x^j+\langle p(x)\rangle \mapsto A^j.$$ The companion matrix property implies that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p(x)$. This means that the ring of matrices
$$\Bbb{F}_p[A]=\{g(A)\mid g(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]\}$$
is isomorphic to the field $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

Comment: One thing caught my eye. The primitive polynomial $p(x)$ is an element of $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. It is not an element of $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$. We often construct the field using a primitive polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$, and then declare $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$.